# JUnit: How to get context on a non activity testCase?

Tags: java, android, junit

I am writing a test class for my non activity class:

```
    public class SinglePhoto {

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

   //---...
}
```

In my test class I need to access the context but I dont know how to do it:

```
    public class SinglePhotoTest extends TestCase {

    public void testDecodeSampledBitmapFromResource() throws Exception {

        SinglePhoto sp = new SinglePhoto();

        Context testContext = ??!

        Bitmap bmp = sp.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(testContext.getResources(), R.drawable.sample, 100, 100);

    }
}
```

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have Application sub class for your app?

Comment: Note: based on some comments on a now-deleted answer, the OP is doing unit testing (`testCompile` with Mockito), not instrumentation testing.

Comment: Add the dependencies in your question. Don't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of extending the TestCase extend the AndroidTestCase. And use the getContext() method to get the context. Here is the AndroidTestCase documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for testing static and other generally "inaccessible" things is probably PowerMockito. There is no short answer for how to use PowerMockito, so I enclose a link for reading: 
http://www.johnmullins.co/blog/2015/02/15/beginners-guide-to-using-mockito-and-powermockito-to-unit-test-java/

Also, extending TestCase is an old-fashion JUnit 3 approach, use the @Test annotation, used from JUnit 4.